# CSS - body background center ignore min-width

Tags: background-image, center, css

This site has a "min-width:600px"  in  BODY, and uses a backgroundImage in Center.

When I resize and It gets lower than 600px, it creates the scroll-bar, fine.
But the background dont stop to center it.. The background ignore the min-width.

My example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/XD4QM/

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            background ignores the min-width

        </div>
    </body>
</html>



body{
    min-width:600px;
    background:url(http://mrknobbymusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/example-last-ones-standing.jpg) center top;

}
```

### Aditional information:

I have a pretty big and bad website to fix.. So like the first move I would like to do this.. This site looks horrible when the person has less than 1024px width (600 was just an example). So I Prefer have the horizontal-scroll and let the site with min-width:1024px and do not destroy the site. Just to keep the client happy until I remake and fix everything.

Comment: Im fairly certain your stuck with this. Backgrounds just don't resize the way you would like

Comment: What are you going for, you want the background-image to fit the size of the window even if its below 600px?

Comment: And setting min-width on the body tag doesn't stop the user from being able to resize the window. I'm not sure what use min-width is, on the body tag.

Comment: @Henrique Kieckbusch - What do you want to happen? You haven't really explained it very well.

Comment: Made a Fiddle - Appreciate but Not Explained It - Poor

Comment: I have a pretty big and bad website to fix.. So like the first move I would like to do this..  This site looks horrible when the person has less than 1024px width (600 was just an example). So I Prefer have the horizontal-scroll and let the site with min-width:1024px and do not destroy the site. Just to keep the client happy until I remake and fix everything.

Comment: I really didnt get the point. I mean, If I have a min-width. So the body will be at least 600pixels, doesnt care what I do. Why the background thinks it has less than that? In my opinion it shouldnt..

Comment: @HenriqueKieckbusch, What is your goal, to have the background get smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wouldn't go with any of the above approaches but change the code to following

`background:url("http://mrknobbymusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/example-last-ones-standing.jpg") repeat scroll center top / cover  transparent;`

notice **top / cover**. **cover** makes sure that **background always resizes along with the div** and background is set as cover of the book in this case as you resize a book, cover resizes itself

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2:

jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/XD4QM/5

```
body{
    width:600px
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
    min-width:800px;
    display: block; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto
}
```

UPDATE:

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/XD4QM/3/

Instead of giving the image to the background where it cannot be controlled, why not put the image inside the div where you can control it?

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

You were not telling the browser to stop repeating the background.

Look at this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/XD4QM/2/

```
body{
    min-width:600px;
    background:url(http://mrknobbymusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/example-last-ones-standing.jpg) center top;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Actually my problem was not the repeating. If the size is 600px. Why it still changing the background position? The center is "300px" right? It should stop.. In my point of view this is a bug. The horizontal scrollbar represents the size is bigger than the script.. so it is erally 600px. Why background center position get coordinates from a strange place?

Comment: You want the background to resize smaller one smaller windows?

Comment: I would like to keep the site as it was 600px looking, when the screen is small than this. But with a horizontal scrollbar.  So if I put 800px image in a 600px place center. It should be 100px I dont see each side of image.  But this "center" in Body background works different.. it uses the browser width to detect the center. And not like a div, or other element that use the element width to get the center.

Comment: Okay, I know what you mean now.  Check back in a second.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I made this way now and worked.

```
@media screen and (max-width :600px){
    body{
        background-position:-<tested value>px 0px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  to toggle between 'scroll' and 'fixed'. The background-attachment property sets whether a background image is fixed or scrolls with the rest of the page.

```
body{
    min-width:600px;
    background:url(example-last-ones-standing.jpg)
    center
    top
    scroll
    no-repeat;
}
```